# Twitter API lets me tweet text but doesn't let me access information about who tagged me

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy, twitter-oauth, twitterapi-python

After authenticating myself using tweepy, I am allowed to post tweets - however, when I try to access a list of all the users that tagged me, it throws an error saying that the app I am using must be in a project - this is despite it being in a project. Anyone have any idea for how to fix this? I tried making the app standalone and then part of the project again, but this didn't help. I am only allowed 25 requests about user information so currently when I run the script, I just get an error about how I made too much requests. I can repost the specific error message when my user request count is reseated tomorrow, but here is my code.

```
client = tweepy.Client(bearerToken,key,keySecret,accessToken,accessTokenSecret)
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(key,keySecret)
auth.set_access_token(accessToken,accessTokenSecret)
api = tweepy.API(auth)

tag = client.get_me()[0]["id"]
print(tag)
print(client.get_user(id=tag))
```

On another note, I do not get the app/project structure of this at all. I am just authenticating myself and then either requesting information or requesting that my text and media be posted. I don't get how the app/project structure helps with this at all.

Thanks for the help, I am on the essential access by the way.